# C# ML.NET Help to Build Complexe Trainer - mlContext.Transforms

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I need to do some machine learning in C# with ML.NET

I have a machine that machines wood parts and I want to predict the machining time of the parts in advance with some mandatory attributes and some that are optional.

some data are more important than others, I don't know if the drive understands it by itself, I think so.

For example the width of the piece of 120 mm or 100 mm will change the machining only of some tenth of second, it is better not to train it for that ?

parts can be passed together, the special machining can change but the tooling for profiling will be almost the same

so I based on a simple calculation if 3 pieces have 9 minutes of machining I redistribute the time of the pieces to 3 minutes per piece

there is obligatorily 1 passage on the 4 lateral faces of the pieces
side_0,side_1,side_2,side_3,

and each part can have additional machining (dowels, lock machining, strike)

What is the best method of creating training?

for the classes of the pieces I use these data (with comments to try to explain)

```
public class ExempleRealTime
{
    // USE // total number of pieces to be synchronized at the same time : exemple 3 pcs
    [LoadColumn(0)]
    public int Group;

    // USE // its total duration, convert TimeSpan in seconds 9,9 min
    [LoadColumn(1)]
    public float GroupDuration;

    // USE // its total duration divised by Group Count, convert TimeSpan in seconds 3,3 min ( 9,9 / 3 )
    [LoadColumn(2)]
    public float Duration;

    // USE // exemple 1000.00f
    [LoadColumn(3)]
    public float Lenght;

    // USE //exemple 100.00f
    [LoadColumn(4)]
    public float Width;

    // USE // exemple 60.00f
    [LoadColumn(5)]
    public float Height;

    // exemple frame or sash
    [LoadColumn(6)]
    public string Structure;

    // IGNORE // exemple [LeftPost,TopTransom,AddedPost]  
    [LoadColumn(7)]
    public string Type;

    // USE // exemple [Pino,Wood,...] - wood change machine speed
    [LoadColumn(8)]
    public string Wood;

    // IGNORE // exemple [HR78,HR68,...] - 
    [LoadColumn(9)]
    public string System;

    // USE // exemple [AAA,BBB,...] - 
    [LoadColumn(10)]
    public string Side_0;

    // USE // exemple [AAA,BBB,...] - 
    [LoadColumn(11)]
    public string Side_1;

    // USE // exemple [AAA,BBB,...] - 
    [LoadColumn(12)]
    public string Side_2;

    // USE // Optional Machining - > Plug/Macro/Panel - exemple [BOHR_08,SERR_2,...]
    [LoadColumn(13)]
    public List<string> OverMachining;

}
```

```
public class ExempleRealTimePrediction
{
    [ColumnName("Score")]
    public float Duration;
}
```

I would like to display the estimated machining time and the probability

the most important in my calculation of time is the group, the more parts that pass at the same time the longer it is but the time saved on the machine movement (moving the axis, change of tools)

make that once the times are divided by the number of parts it becomes more profitable

and the SIDE and OverMachining are the options that make all the difference, a SIDE contains a name of cycles that makes predefined passages of tool and same for the OverMachining

if you have ideas to build the model, I will then make modifications to make my code more readable

```
 private static ITransformer BuildTrainEvaluateAndSaveModel(MLContext mlContext)
        {
            // STEP 1: Common data loading configuration
            IDataView baseTrainingDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<MachineLearning.Model.RealTime>(TrainDataPath, hasHeader: false, separatorChar: ',');
          
            IDataView trainingDataView = mlContext.Data.FilterRowsByColumn(baseTrainingDataView, nameof(MachineLearning.Model.RealTime.Duration), lowerBound: 1, upperBound: 30);
           
            // STEP 2: Common data process configuration with pipeline data transformations
            var dataProcessPipeline = mlContext.Transforms.CopyColumns(outputColumnName: "Label", inputColumnName: nameof(MachineLearning.Model.RealTime.Duration))
                            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "GroupEncoded", inputColumnName: nameof(MachineLearning.Model.RealTime.Group)))
                            // .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "RateCodeEncoded", inputColumnName: nameof(MachineLearning.Model.RealTime.GroupDuration)))
                            //.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "PaymentTypeEncoded", inputColumnName: nameof(MachineLearning.Model.RealTime.PaymentType)))
                            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeMeanVariance(outputColumnName: nameof(MachineLearning.Model.RealTime.Lenght)))
                            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeMeanVariance(outputColumnName: nameof(MachineLearning.Model.RealTime.Width)))
                            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeMeanVariance(outputColumnName: nameof(MachineLearning.Model.RealTime.Height)))
                            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features",
                            "GroupEncoded",
                            //"RateCodeEncoded",
                            //"PaymentTypeEncoded",
                            nameof(MachineLearning.Model.RealTime.Lenght),
                            nameof(MachineLearning.Model.RealTime.Width),
                            nameof(MachineLearning.Model.RealTime.Height)));

            // (OPTIONAL) Peek data (such as 5 records) in training DataView after applying the ProcessPipeline's transformations into "Features" 
            //ConsoleHelper.PeekDataViewInConsole(mlContext, trainingDataView, dataProcessPipeline, 5);
            // ConsoleHelper.PeekVectorColumnDataInConsole(mlContext, "Features", trainingDataView, dataProcessPipeline, 5);

            // STEP 3: Set the training algorithm, then create and config the modelBuilder - Selected Trainer (SDCA Regression algorithm)                            
            var trainer = mlContext.Regression.Trainers.Sdca(labelColumnName: "Label", featureColumnName: "Features");
            var trainingPipeline = dataProcessPipeline.Append(trainer);

            // STEP 4: Train the model fitting to the DataSet
            //The pipeline is trained on the dataset that has been loaded and transformed. 
            Console.WriteLine("=============== Training the model ===============");
            var trainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(trainingDataView);


            // STEP 5: Evaluate the model and show accuracy stats
            //Console.WriteLine("===== Evaluating Model's accuracy with Test data ====="); 
            //  IDataView predictions = trainedModel.Transform(testDataView); 
            //  var metrics = mlContext.Regression.Evaluate(predictions, labelColumnName: "Label", scoreColumnName: "Score"); 
            //  Common.ConsoleHelper.PrintRegressionMetrics(trainer.ToString(), metrics);





            // STEP 6: Save/persist the trained model to a .ZIP file 

            mlContext.Model.Save(trainedModel, trainingDataView.Schema, ModelPath);

            Console.WriteLine("The model is saved to {0}", ModelPath);

            return trainedModel;
        }
```

on my class that I shared with you I made tests much less complex but it's already outside the nails I have the impression .